# how polymorphism method matches in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm puzzled how Java polymorphism works.
In the case below, there are three polymorphism methods of `showText`, for distinguishing clearly, these methods names `method-1`, `method-2`, `method-3`.  codes as below:

```java
public class PolymorphismTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showText("def");
    }

    // method-1
    private static void showText(Object abc) {
        print("1.....");
        showText(abc, "abc");
    }

    // method-2
    private static void showText(Object abc, String item) {
        // print(abc.getClass().getName());
        print("2.....");
        String text;
        if (abc == null) {
            text = null;
        } else {
            text = abc.toString();
        }
        showText(text, item);
    }

    // method-3
    private static void showText(String abc, String item) {
        print("3.....");
    }

    private static void print(String text) {
        System.out.print(text);
    }
}
```

- method-1 has one parameter of type `Object`
- method-2 has two parameters, the parameter type are `Object` and `String`
- method-3 has two parameters, the same param count with `method-2`, while its first param type is `String`

The `main()` calls `method-1` with a parameter of type `String`, in the body of `method-1` it calls another method, which one is matched, `method-2` or `method-3`?

I test it in java 8, the out put is

```
1.....2.....3.....
```

Comment: Java method overload resolution is done at compile time and not runtime. You asked which method is matched and kind of gave yourself the answer with your output. But the reason your first method calls the second is like already said this is determined during compile time, so `Object abc` is just an object and therefor the compiler decides that the method that accepts an Object is the right one to call. All that is done when you compile your program. That you later pass a String as the actual object doesn't matter

Comment: so... basically: how does method overloading work? Have you read a textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload is decided at **compile-time**, so when the first method gets the `abc` parameter it sees it as an `Object` (not a `String`) and calls `method-2` which has the appropriate signature for it.

You are probably confused because this is different from the dynamic linking mechanism, which applies to class instances (objects) methods, and resolves the method **at runtime** based on the actual class of the instance on which the call is made (for example `toString()` in `abc.toString()`).